# CouchDB array passing

Tags: javascript, nosql, couchdb

I'm trying to passing an arguments (array) for update, but seems CouchDB unable to parse them correctly.

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/mydb/_design/timeline/_update/hello/container-1?tags\\[\\]=1\&tags\\[\\]=2
```

in CouchDB:

```
  "updates": {
       "hello": "function(doc,request){if(!doc){doc={_id:request.id};}for(i in request.query){doc[i]=request.query[i];}return[doc,JSON.stringify(request.query)];}"
   }
```

In this case, only last passed value returned, as:

```
{"tags[]":"2"}
```

Looks like it doesn't understand standard passing array.
How to pass array and to parse it in CouchDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found [here](http://www.listware.net/201007/couchdb-user/52621-changes-to-list-functions-reqquery-in-couchdb-100.html) undocumented feature, that works fine for me:

```
?param=1&tags=[1, 2, 3]&....
```

Comment: That link doesn't seem to point to any CouchDB information. Can anyone explain this 'undocumented feature' in more detail?

Comment: There's 7 years old link that doesn't work anymore. I think I changed anyway now in CouchDB.

Comment: I've just started experimenting with passing arrays in the body of a request to an update handler and have been starting to see it working. Still need to do a lot of testing, etc., but this seems the best solution so far.